# Is there any way I can get this list of phrases of Azure weather API?

Tags: azure, api, weather

Using the Azure weather API, I would like to know what weather possibilities it can bring in the "phrase" field.

In the documentation, we have a list of icons ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/weather-services-concepts#weather-icons)), which gives a clue about this, but in this list there are some things that are certainly not the weather.

Is there any way I can get this list of phrases?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the [Get-Current-Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/weather/get-current-conditions?tabs=HTTP) Weather REST API to Successfully retrieve detailed current weather conditions and in the response it will list out the various phrases that are available.

Alternatively, Please refer the list of the enums available for `phrase` in [**this**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/280a956db30d829fa65a9c0fdede073261ad76bf/specification/maps/data-plane/Weather/stable/1.1/weather.json#L1298) REST API Specs article.